# Assert that text has been input - Selenium Web Driver

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium Webdriver C# in Visual Studio 2013, using namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

I need to assert that the text I have input into the field using `firstName.SendKey("1")` has been input into the field successfully. This is to ensure the rules for that field are working correctly:

```
string id = "mainContentPlaceHolder_registrationWizard_txtFirstname";
IWebElement firstName = driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
firstName.SendKeys("1");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to try

*[Assert.AreEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243437.aspx)*

```
string id = "mainContentPlaceHolder_registrationWizard_txtFirstname";
IWebElement firstName = driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
firstName.SendKeys("1");

Assert.AreEqual(firstName.GetAttribute("value"),"1")
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure why you are getting that. See [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) and if you can provide me the `html` snippet I would love to investigate.